# postgresql 11 ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"

Tags: postgresql

I installed Mimic3 database in Pg11, and try to query using the code from here: https://mimic.physionet.org/tutorials/intro-to-mimic-iii-bq/ solution to step 1.

```
SELECT ie.subject_id, ie.hadm_id, ie.icustay_id,
    ie.intime, ie.outtime
FROM `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays` ie;
```

but I got the error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 3: FROM `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays` ie
             ^
, Time: 0.004000s
```

And if I deleted those two backticks, I got the warning.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 3: FROM physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays ie
                      ^
, Time: 0.002000s
```

And if I explaced ` with ", it showed the error that:

```
ERROR:  relation "physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays" does not exist
LINE 3: FROM "physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays" ie
             ^
, Time: 0.002000s
```

Hope somebody can tell me what was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't use backticks to quote table names, it uses double quotes, and dots aren't allowed in names without quoting, so you probably want this:

```
SELECT ie.subject_id, ie.hadm_id, ie.icustay_id,
    ie.intime, ie.outtime
FROM "physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays" ie;
```

Comment: But it showed new error: `ERROR:  relation "physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.icustays" does not exist`

Comment: Well, does it exist?

Comment: If the dots are meant to be schema separators, then they need to go outside the quotes.

Comment: @jjanes True, but that still won't make sense in Postgres, because there are _three_ parts to the name, not two. In some systems, like Microsoft SQL Server, that is valid, because it represents "database.schema.table", but you can't query across databases that way in Postgres. Besides, it would leave the question of why they were quoted (with backticks) in the original tutorial.

Comment: You can use three parts in PostgreSQL, as long as the first one matches the name of the database you are connected to--it is a bit weird, but possible.  Maybe whatever database that was written for puts the dots inside the ticks, I don't know what other databases do in that regard.